# Is it possible to use 'last ... ' or any past simple adverbs with the past perfect?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, past-perfect

To illustrate what I mean, I give the following example:

> I had drifted off to sleep last night.

Comment: *Last* as used here is an adjective, not an adverb. And what to you mean by *past simple adverb*?

Comment: _Last_ as used here is a determiner: **Last** can be used in the following ways:
[1] as a determiner (followed by a noun): I saw him last night. ♦ I wasn't here last time. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/last) 'Last' is specifying which night rather than describing the type of night. Compare 'this evening'; 'every evening'.

Comment: Adverbs don't have tense, do they?

Answer (score 1):

FYI: "Last" isn't an adverb here, it's an adjective describing the night. An example of an adverb might be:

> I *slowly* drifted off to sleep last night.

*Slowly* describes how you drifted off.

---

Given that you meant adjective, consider the following:

The [past perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) is used when you are discussing one event in the past in relation to another.

> I had drifted off to sleep last night, then a car alarm woke me.

You should use [past simple](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html) in this case:

> I drifted off to sleep last night.

Your other option would be to use the [past continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) tense. This is used when the action was taking place for an extended amount of time:

> I was drifting off to sleep last night when a car alarm work me.

Comment: The sentence is not ungrammatical, it just requires the right context to be grammatical. Discussing one event in relation to another does not necessarily mean the two have to be expressed in the same sentence. “I had drifted off to sleep almost immediately last night. It was barely five minutes later, though, that a car alarm woke me up, and then I couldn't get back to sleep at all” is perfectly grammatical.